# Where do I view event parameters with Facebook Analytics App Events?

Tags: android, analytics, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using Facebook analytics in my Android app to log app events - I'm seeing the correct tracking of app events and am able to view them in my Facebook App Analytics dashboard.

However, I have no idea where parameters that I attach to each event are displayed. Some of them are automatically summed and shown - for instance, purchases or other values. For other, string-based parameters, however, I'm unable to figure out where I can view them.

As an example:

Say every time something goes wrong in my app, I log an event named `"Error"`. I then pass the parameter named `AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_DESCRIPTION` a string description - so this might be `"App Crashed"` or `"No Internet Connection"` or something. Let's say one of each happens.

When I go to view my analytics, I will correctly see that there have been two `"Error"` events. But now I want to know whether these were instances of `"App Crashed"` or `"No Internet Connection"` - presumably that's what the point of the parameters is. How do I do this? I've googled and clicked everything I can think of, but haven't found a way to see the parameter breakdown of an event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, its not simple to find that information. You will need to use Segments in Facebook Analytics for that. Go to Segments and try creating a new segment. Define Condition Type as "Events". Then select the Event then you want to include. After that, select the option of "Refine". This will show you "Select a Parameter". Here you can select the parameter that you want to see and its value. Save this segment, and use it in any chart you want.

Unfortunately, that is the best way I have found, though it is not as straightforward as it should be.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick. 

(Wow, that is an exceptionally non-intuitive and poorly documented place to view the information - and not super helpful either. Was hoping it would be more straightforward...ah well.)

Comment: I cannot find "Segment" in Facebook Analytics. Is "Segment" changed to "Breakdown" now?

Comment: @JoeHuang Yes, looks like this has been changed - see below for a detailed answer by photogrammer . Unfortunately it's still convoluted to get this information, but it should be possible.

Answer (score 13):

I can confirm that it is troublesome to find and the name has been changed to "Breakdowns"...

- Activity -> Breakdowns
- click "Create New" in upper right
- give the report a NAME
- select the top level event from the EVENT pop-up
- select one or more parameters to report on from the 3 BREAKDOWN
  pop-ups (note that your custom parameters appear at the bottom of
  these menus)

Comment: What is the french translation of this "Breakdowns" menu? All what I see in the activity menu is : 
Utilisateurs actifs, 
Revenus, 
Entonnoirs, 
Rétention, 
Groupes, 
Détails, 
Parcours, 
Centiles, 
Évènements, 
Débug des évènements, 
Chevauchement, 
Valeur globale . // Where is the breakdown menu? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the ways based on the answers provided here. But the fact is, it is tedious or going round the bush.

The answer is simple, just send the values and parameters wrapped inside "contents".

It will be visible on your analytics dashboard the same as standard events do.

```
var name = "Dhinesh";
var platformName = "flutter";
//custom event - fb analytics
fbq('trackCustom', 'FreeTrialPlatform',
  // begin parameter object data
  {
    contents: [{
      name: name,
      platform: platformName
    }],
    content_type: 'product'
  }
  // end parameter object data
);
```

[View in fb analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riLb7.png)

For your case like this,

```
var errorName = "App crashed";
fbq('trackCustom', 'TrackError', {
  contents: [{
    Error: errorName
  }],
});
```